# Mysql: ignore 2 distinct columns from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have 2 tables that are something like this:

```
Table1:
animal  name  color
cat     bob   red
dog     bill  blue

Table2:  
animal  name
cat     bob
fish    joe
```

I want to query all the data in table 1 except if they have the unique identity from table 2, so I would get dog bill blue, and not the cat, since it appears in table 2.

I did:

```
select t.animal, t.name, t.color
from Table1 as t, Table2 as t2
where NOT(t.animal = t2.animal AND
          t.name = t2.name)
group by t.animal, t.name
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.animal, t.name, t.color
from Table1 as t 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t.animal = t2.animal and t.name = t2.name
where table2.name is null
group by t.animal, t.name
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `where not exists` clause should do the trick:

```
select t1.animal, t1.name, t1.color
from Table1 t1
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from Table2 t2
    where t2.animal = t1.animal
    and t2.name = t1.name
)
```

You can also use the anti-join pattern:

```
select t1.animal, t1.name, t1.color
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on t1.animal = t2.animal and t1.name = t2.name
where t2.animal is null
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_one t1 
  WHERE t1.animal NOT IN 
                     (SELECT animal FROM table_two)
```